# Device information from Rest request

Tags: java, android, ios, rest, web

Hi I have an application that is receiving rest request from multiple clients(android, IOS, web client). Can I get which device has sent me the particular Rest Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST simply a specification to implement the entities operations on top of HTTP methods. For any REST implementation, you need to have a contract between client and server to share the information. The information can be shared as part of HTTP request body or headers.

So if you need the device info from the clients, then client should send it as part of a header or a request parameter. As the provider of your REST services, you need to publish the information to the clients, which request header/param they need to send the device info.

Answer (score 0):

just add a parameter in your webservice which will get device name or whatever information do you want to send and you can get device info by bellow code.

```
NSLog(@"uniqueIdentifier: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]);
NSLog(@"name: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]);
NSLog(@"systemName: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName]);
NSLog(@"systemVersion: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]);
NSLog(@"model: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] model]);
NSLog(@"localizedModel: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] localizedModel]);
```